# How can I connect a MacBook Pro (early 2011) to two monitors?

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro, multiple-monitors

I would like to connect my work MacBook Pro to two (or even three) monitors to get more screen real estate.

There is [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIVZI1cFiAw) but it uses a USB-DVI adapter and by design is a bit laggy.

Any other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Matrox TripleHead2Go seems like it would fit the bill. They also make a DualHead2Go.

Answer (score 0):

I have the setup the poster used in the video. I can testify there's no lag. You can't use the DVD player on the USB-connected monitor but other than that it works great.